# getting the line up logo and nav inside the header

Tags: html, css

I am completely new to html and css, I am trying to get the logo for my site and the navigation to display next to each other, rather than underneath. 
I just simply can't figure out what is going wrong.

I have listed my html followed by my css below. My css is it's own file I just couldn't figure out how to seperate them on here.

```
<!--Header-->
        <header>    
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Lost Collector" title="Lost Collector"/>
            </a>
            <!--Primary navigation-->
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>


header a img {
  margin-top: 10px; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline;}

nav {
display: inline;
float: right;}

nav ul  {
list-style: none;
display: inline;}

 nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 90%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #069;
padding: 4px 3px;}

nav li a {
display: inline-block;
padding: 4px 3px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 90%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #069;}
```

Here is a screenshot of what my page looks like, you can see the navigation is below the logo I am trying to get it to display to the right on the same line as the logo. 
http://postimg.org/image/rjqjmrog1/

I worked the problem out using jsfiddle,
https://jsfiddle.net/2fwvzb7s/1/
in there is loads correctly, but when I open my page in chrome it loads wrong, so I am very confused.

Comment: Check the width of your image to make sure it isn't forcing the nav onto the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its working well, can you please elaborate the issue.**

```css
 header a{float:left; display:inline-block}
header a img {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline;
  height:45px;
}
nav {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #069;
  padding: 4px 3px;
}
nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #069;
}
```

```html
<!--Header-->
<header>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://step.wiwi.uni-kl.de/fileadmin/wd2013/fb-logo/fb_logo_dummy.png" alt="Lost Collector" title="Lost Collector" />
  </a>
  <!--Primary navigation-->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I have added a link to a screenshot of what it currently looks like for clarification.

Comment: please try the updated code above, hopefully it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Your welcome bro, please vote up ^ if the answer was promising :)